# Regex - Does not contain certain Characters

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I need a regex to match if anywhere in a sentence there is NOT either `<` or `>`.

If either `<` or `>` are in the string then it must return false.

I had a partial success with this but only if my `<` `>` are at the beginning or end:

```
(?!<|>).*$
```

I am using .Net if that makes a difference.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 676, accepted):

```
^[^<>]+$
```

The caret in the character class (`[^`) means match anything but, so this means, beginning of string, then one or more of anything except `<` and `>`, then the end of the string.

Comment: What does the first caret mean? Would this mean not anything that does not contain those characters... thus meaning only strings that do contain those characters?

Comment: The first caret means, beginning of string.  The dollar means, end of string.

Comment: @PhilipRego Be careful with special characters: the shell interprets some of them.  Look to see if you now have a file named ']+$' in your directory.  Put the entire regex inside single quotes to make it work.

Comment: Great answer! Could you add an explanation of why there is a `+` and the first caret?

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś "+" means "one or more", and "^" means "beginning of string".

Comment: Stupid me, didn't think to this! Speaking becomes: expect `^` _beginning of string_ `[^]` _any char but_ `<>` _either of these two literals_ `+` _for one or more times_ `$` _end of string_ .   Also, without plus sign it would expect a string of one single char long. Replace `+` with `*` to match empty strings too.

Comment: This works great in JS/PHP/Python as well, here is the [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/6db0167b2cfc) if you are interested.

Answer (score 98):

Here you go:

```
^[^<>]*$
```

This will test for string that has no `<` and no `>`

If you want to test for a string that may have `<` and `>`, but must also have something other you should use just

```
[^<>] (or ^.*[^<>].*$)
```

Where `[<>]` means *any of `<` or `>`* and `[^<>]` means *any that is not of `<` or `>`*.

And of course the mandatory [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).