# How to make a regex pattern in Razor/MVC3 to exempt certain characters

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I would like to know how to write a pattern for a regex in Razor/MVC3. I have been searching how to write the pattern but since I didn't know anything about MVC/Razor I only found a regex pattern for

```
characters only
^[a-zA-Z]+$

numbers only
^[0-9]*$

character and numbers only
^\w+$

email address. 
/\S+@\S+\.\S+/
```

Those patterns I found are not the one I am looking for. I would like to create a pattern which will exempt these characters `"&';,<>`.
I thought of one way doing it. Like this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_!#$%()-=~^|+and so on..]*$
```

Do I have to list all the characters just to exempt those? Or there is more an efficient way of doing it?

Comment: Like this? `^[^"&';,<>]*$`

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie Doesn't that accept only those characters in your string? I want to exempt those.

Comment: The caret inside the character class indicates that the match should exclude the characters within the class: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated

Comment: Ah. I see. Thank you. I'll try that if it works in my site. :)

Comment: `[RegularExpression(@"^[^" & ';,<>]*$")]` Using this is not working because this can't be a whole string because of the " that is included in the excluded characters. @SimonMᶜKenzie

Comment: Then you need to either use a verbatim string or escape the quote, e.g. `@"^[^"" & ';,<>]*$"` or `"^[^\" & ';,<>]*$"`.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie please see the update. :) Thank youuuu. Please write it as the answer below. :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex - Does not contain certain Characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105956/regex-does-not-contain-certain-characters)

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

I have used this `@"^[^"" & ';,<>]*$"` as suggested by Simon in the comments, and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this ?

```
 "[<>'"/;&]"
```

Comment: No not yet I am still trying to incorporate it in my website.