# Efficient way to extract data within double quotes

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I need to extract the data within double quotes from a string.

Input:

```
<a href="Networking-denial-of-service.aspx">Next Page →</a>
```

Output:

```
Networking-denial-of-service.aspx
```

Currently, I am using following method to do this and it is running fine.

```
atag = '<a href="Networking-denial-of-service.aspx">Next Page →</a>'
start = 0
end = 0

for i in range(len(atag)):
    if atag[i] == '"' and start==0:
        start = i
    elif atag[i] == '"' and end==0: 
        end = i

nxtlink = atag[start+1:end]
```

So, my question is that is there any other efficient way to do this task.

Thankyou.

Comment: There are [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) of course, but it's [strongly discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not) to use them for HTML because you can miss a lot of cases. The "right" way to do it would be to use [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) (or something on top of that) to parse the HTML and then select the nodes you need and read their attributes.

Comment: @CherryDT Can you please provide a sample code or something.

Comment: I'm not really into python, so I don't feel confident providing an example. That's why this is a comment and not an answer. But what I said (there are regexes, but a HTML parser is preferred) applies to other languages as well.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you might already find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612548/extracting-an-attribute-value-with-beautifulsoup

Comment: Thanks for the link, it works. I suggest you to write is as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Since I'm not sure which of the examples works best for your case and I'm not proficient enough to create a modified version, please add an answer yourself where you describe the final solution and accept it. This way others can still find the answer easily. It's fine that I don't get rep for this one. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged this beautifulsoup so I don't see why you want a regex, if you want the href from all anchors then you can use a css select `'a[href]'` which will only find anchor tags that have href attributes:

```
h = '''<a href="Networking-denial-of-service.aspx">Next Page →</a>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(h)

print(soup.select_one('a[href]')["href"])
```

Or find:

```
 print(soup.find('a', href=True)["href"])
```

If you have multiple:

```
for  a in soup.select_one('a[href]'):
    print a["href"]
```

Or:

```
for  a in  soup.find_all("a", href=True):
     print a["href"]
```

You could also specify that you want hrefs that have a leading ":

```
 soup.select_one('a[href^="]')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am taking the question exactly as written - how to get data between two double quotes. I agree with the comments that an HTMLParser might be better...

Using regular expression might help, particularly if you want to find more than one. For example, this is a possible set of code

```
import re
string_with_quotes = 'Some "text" "with inverted commas"\n "some text \n with a line break"'

Find_double_quotes = re.compile('"([^"]*)"', re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE|re.IGNORECASE) # Ignore case not needed here, but can be useful.

list_of_quotes = Find_double_quotes.findall(string_with_quotes)

list_of_quotes

['text', 'with inverted commas', 'some text \n with a line break']
```

If you have an odd number of double quotes, then the last double quote is ignored. If none are found, then an empty list is produced.

Various references

http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is really good for learning regular expressions

[Regex - Does not contain certain Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105956/regex-does-not-contain-certain-characters) gave me how not to do a character

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE tells you what re.MULTILINE and re.DOTALL (underneath) do.

Comment: Thats really nice of you to provide code and links.