# Regex to match only strings that don't contain specific character

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Looking to write some regex to match only the strings in the follow that don't contain a pipe.

```
4 Canciones: No. 2, Dices que no la quieres
5 Canciones canciones para niños: No. 1, Balada
Spanish; Castilian | es
Spanish; Castilian | es
El molinero
Spanish; Castilian | es
```

So far I've got

```
^(?!\|).+
```

But it simply matches the first string and stops after that.

Looking for all advice. Thanks!

Comment: `^[^|]+$` but this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105956

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex - Does not contain certain Characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105956/regex-does-not-contain-certain-characters)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over each line and keep those that match. The regex

```
^(?!.*\|).+
```

should work for your examples.

Comment: `^[^|]+$` is sufficient. Your solution uses a double parsing.