# Python Regex All Alphabet unless "X"

Tags: python

I have tried

```
if re.match('.*[a-zA-Z].*' ,funcion) and not re.match("[x]", funcion):
```

It actually works, but I want to make my code *smaller* and I guess there is an option for reducing it. Like `re.match('.*[a-zA-Z]^x.*' ,funcion)`, but it doesnt really work.

UPDATE:

I just made this:

```
if re.match('.*[a-zA-Z].*' ,funcion) and not re.match("x", funcion) and not re.match("[1-9]", funcion):
```

This works well, because I want to put functions like 7x + 3, and doing the upper thing wont work with 7x because it detects it. There should be a way to make this a pattern..

FULL CODE OF MY PROGRAM

```
while True:
  
  
   funcion = input("")
   if re.match('.*[a-zA-Z].*' ,funcion) and not re.match("x", funcion) and not re.match("[1-9]", funcion):
    print("Incorrecto, contiene una letra")
    
  

   elif "x" not in funcion:
      print("No contiene la X necesaria en una funcion.")

   else:
    break
"
```

Comment: try `'[a-wyzA-WYZ]' `

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex - Does not contain certain Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105956/regex-does-not-contain-certain-characters)

Answer (score 2):

You may express the pattern as `^[a-wyz]+$`:

```
inp = ["Hello", "World", "taxes"]
for i in inp:
    if re.search(r'^[a-wyz]+$', i, flags=re.I):
        print("MATCH:    " + i)
    else:
        print("NO MATCH: " + i)
```

This prints:

```
MATCH:    Hello
MATCH:    World
NO MATCH: taxes
```

Comment: It doesnt work, Lx for example is also matched. only 7x or x should work.

Comment: Edit your question and add sample data.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will work:

```
re.match('^[^xX]+$', text)
```

Comment: It doesnt, (letter)x is also matched.

Comment: notice there are 2 "^", in the beginning and inside "[^xX]"