# Check the format of a string with numbers with grepl

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I want to check if a string has either this format "1234.34" or this "1234".
I tried the following using grepl in R (1 or more numbers, a dot or not followed by more numbers):

```
grepl("([[:digit:]]+\\.?[[:digit:]]*)", c("1234.34", "1234,34", "1234"))
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

With 1234.34 or 1234 it works fine (both TRUE).

If I test "1234,34" (with "comma"), the expression becomes TRUE, but I expected FALSE.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105956/regex-does-not-contain-certain-characters

Answer (score 2):

You could just include both options in the regex pattern: either only digits or digits + dot + more digits. Separate both options with a pipe `|`:

```r
x <- c("1234.34", "1234,34", "1234")
grepl("^\\d+$|^\\d+\\.\\d+$", x)
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

As long as the string does only contain numbers, you could do the following that searches for anything that's not a comma:

```
x <- c("1234", "1234.34", "1234,34")
grepl("^[^,]+$", x)

[1]  TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: This wouldn't work with `"12.34.5"`

Comment: That is true - it is definitely prone to errors - but depending on the data it could suffice here :)